# Update WooCommerce variable product attribute variation checkbox during product import

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a plugin which extends the WooCommerce importer so that I can create a variable product with all variations in one step. For that, I need to update the product attribute and enable the variation checkbox for each attribute:

[image]

```
/**
 * Process the data read from the CSV file
 *
 * @param WC_Product|null|false $product
 * @param array $data
 *
 * @return WC_Product|null|false
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_product_import_pre_insert_product_object', 'filter_woocommerce_product_import_pre_insert_product_object', 10, 2);
function filter_woocommerce_product_import_pre_insert_product_object($product, array $data): object {
    $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    if (!empty($product_attributes) && $product->is_type('variable')) {
        error_log(print_r($product_attributes, true));

        /**
         * @var WC_Product_Attribute $product_attribute
         */
        foreach ($product_attributes as $product_attribute) {
            $product_attribute_id = $product_attribute->get_id();

            wc_update_attribute($product_attribute_id, [
                'variation' => '1'
            ]);
        }

        error_log(print_r($product->get_attributes(), true));
    }

    return $product;
}
```

The code get's called but somehow it's not updating my checkbox. I really don't know whats wrong. No error in the logs or from any function call.

Comment: I've currently opened a ticket at the WooCommerce GitHub waiting for any response about this topic. There is a logic inside WooCommerce which kills metas when an element get's trashed and untrashed so no idea how to get handled here. We will see. I'll update the question ASAP I've a response.

Comment: Any news to this?